# Regex: Remove duplicate lines that are next to each other

Tags: python, regex

I've extracted some cc from Youtube and I'm stuck with values like below and I don't know how to deal with it. I'm good at replacing strings and other stuff, but I'm really bad when things get serious :(

This

```
 we
 all
 have
 a
 unique
 perspective
 on
 the
 we all have a unique perspective on the

 we all have a unique perspective on the
 world
 around
 us
 and
 believe
 it
 or
 not
 world around us and believe it or not

 world around us and believe it or not
```

should be replaced by :

```
we all have a unique perspective on the
world around us and believe it or not
```

Comment: Why do you need to use regex for this? What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python

Comment: `sed -n -e '/^$/{x;p;d;}' -e x file.txt` looks like it might work (print only lines before empty lines)

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but for the moment I'm using the notepad++ find/replace regex. I want to make it work localy before I even try to integrate it to my Python code.

Comment: It looks like this is a text only (not regex) problem. Specifically, based on *too little data,* it seems like the first line after a blank line is the "real text" and any following stuff can be ignored. Check to see if that pattern holds, because that's an easy python script to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this regex, you can get rid of all lines that just have a single word and if there are lines having multiple words and are exactly repeating, they will be replaced with just single line,

```
\w+\s*\n|([\w ]+)\n*(\1\n+)*
```

Here first part in alternation `\w+\s*\n` matches single word line and is replaced with empty string and second alternation `([\w ]+)\n*(\1\n+)*` captures a line in group1 and then `(\1\n+)*` consumes any repeated line and is finally replaced by group2 which is the same line repeating multiple times.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/45mfQi/1)**